# Is there a batch commandfor windows 10 to register a file extension?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, file-extension

For example, I have a batch program which helps keep track of homework assignments, which we'll say is located at `.../hwhelper.bat`. It stores each assignment in a file with a *.hw file extension. In windows 10 (and up?), next to certain file extensions, it will say something (for example, an exe will say 'Application', and *.txt files will say 'Text Document'. How would I make it so it will say 'Homework Helper Assignment' next to it and clicking on an assignment will open the `hwhelper.bat` file?

Comment: Yes, there are registry entries, you can use to associate file extensions with executable applications.

Comment: [Implementing a Custom File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper), [File Types and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-intro)

Answer (score 3):

In the command prompt type:

```
FTYPE /?
```

and:

```
ASSOC /?
```

Check out these pages:

https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html

https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html

Comment: The Microsoft documentation for the [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) documents also [assoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) and [ftype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype). Both are listed also in list output on running `help` in a command prompt window and so `help assoc` or `assoc /?` and `help ftype` or `ftype /?` can be used also to get displayed their usage helps.